# Undefined reference to file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to link/reference separate files together for compilation. I've never done this before, so I'm lost with this error. It *seems* like I've referenced what I need.

I've got three files, main.cpp, parser.cpp and header.h
Main calls parser to parse text (although I haven't been able to test if it actually works yet :l )

***main.cpp -***

```
#include "header.h"

using namespace std; // I know this isn't recommended, I'm changing this later.

        int main(){
    string input, arg1, arg2;
    vector<string> parsedIn;
    cout << "<";
    while(getline(cin, input)){


            parsedIn = parser(input);
            //more code, this is the only call to parser and compile error 
            //stops here
```

***parser.cpp -***

```
#include "header.h"

std::vector<std::string> parser(std::string &input){
int i=0;
//int begin=1;
int  count=0;
std::vector<std::string> parsedIn;

        while(i<input.length()){

                char temp = input.at(i);
                if(temp != ' '){
                parsedIn[count] += temp;
                count++;
                }
        i++;
        }

        if(count < 3)
        parsedIn[0] = "Error"; // Set first value to "Error" to report an input issue

return parsedIn;
}
```

***header.h***

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

std::vector<std::string> parser(std::string &input);
```

I know I should be using guards as well, but my TA wasn't exactly clear on how I set those up...baby steps though. This is my first time with C++ so I'd like to figure out why this isn't being referenced.

The error is undefined reference to parser, of course.

Edit: I made changes to the code to reflect what I've done at your suggestion.

Specifically parse(std::string &input) has become parser(std::string &input)

Comment: Paste the commands you are using to attempt to compile and/or link.

Comment: What command do you execute immediately before you get the error? Hit the compike button/gcc/whatever...

Comment: Is this code the same you are compiling? You have a function called parser in header.h, and another called parse in parser.cpp.

Comment: To compile, I've been doing g++ main.cpp

I didn't think it should be any different than normal.

Comment: @Clark Please post the exact error message. That would be helpful.

Comment: `code`
> g++ main.cpp
/tmp/ccj3B5K4.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x304): undefined reference to `parser(std::string&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`code`

Comment: @Clark Thats a linker error. You are not compiling `parser.cpp`. Try - `g++ main.cpp parser.cpp`

Comment: That solved it. I was under the impression that the compiler would find all files to be compiled once you linked it. Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 7):

parser.cpp has the "parser" method spelled "parse", but your header.h says it's named "parser".

Comment: Wow that was really obvious. I changed it, but I'm still getting the same compile error. So is there something else?

I also made the changes Mahesh pointed out below with vectors.

Comment: @clark My changes has nothing to do with the compilation issue. Accessing invalid indexes is a run-time issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have another problem.

```
std::vector<std::string> parsedIn;
// ...
parsedIn[count] += temp;
```

Size of the vector `parsedIn` in 0. Using `[]` on an empty vector causes undefined behavior. You need to perform [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) operations to add elements to the vector. Unlike `std::map` container, you can not use `[]` operator to add elements to the vector.

Comment: Do you mean "Unlike `std::map`..."?

Comment: @MooingDuck If you see my last-1 edit, it was "Unlike `std::map`". I felt the meaning would turn other wise if I used "Unlike". I think you are correct. Still struggling with English :P

Comment: Is it okay to reference non-empty vectors like this?

Say I have a vector with 3 items inside, could I evaluate the contents with something like 'if(parsedIn[1] == "foo")' ?

Comment: Yes. You can do that as long as the vector has elements. But make sure that you are not crossing vector's bounds. Meaning if the vector has 3 elements, you can only access index 0,1,2. Any other index is not a valid index.

Answer (score 0):

You are failing to **link** your files.

Small steps:

1) Write `helloWorld` if you haven't already. The source file can be called `hello.cpp`.

2) Instead of building in one step from source to executable, like this:

```
g++ hello.cpp
```

try building the *object file*, `hello.o`, then building the executable out of that:

```
g++ -c hello.cpp -o hello.o
g++ hello.o -o hello
```

3) Add some little function, call it `void foo()`, that takes no arguments, returns nothing, prints out something and does nothing else. Put it in `hello.cpp` and **do not proceed until it works perfectly.**

4) Move `foo()` to its own source file (`foo.cpp`) and header file (`foo.h`). Don't worry about header guards for now. Compile and build like this:

```
g++ -c hello.cpp -o hello.o
g++ -c foo.cpp -o foo.o
g++ hello.o foo.o -o hello
```

If you get this far, you've done pretty well.